# Geometric meaning of double derivatives

Tags: geometry, derivatives

Specifically I want to interpret what f"(x)=0 means geometrically.

Comment: $f'' = 0$ on an interval $\implies f'(x)=b$ is constant $\implies f(x)=ax+b$ for $a,b \in \Bbb R$. Any convex and concave function is affine.

Comment: [These notes might be helpful](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ShapeofGraphPtII.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If $f''(x)=0$ for all $x$, that means $f(x)$ is a linear function.

On the other hand, if $f(x)$ is not linear, you set $f''(x)$ equal to $0$ (and solve for $x$) to find the points of inflection of $f(x)$. The points of inflection are where the graph of the function changes from concave up to concave down and vice versa.